# How to make span appear under another span?

Tags: html, css

I tried to make animated intro to my site, but I dont know how to make animated background appear before span with text.

I'v already tried using `z-index` but it didn't seem to work.

```css
#frontcolor {
  z-index: 2;
  animation: revBackDrop 1s linear 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eceff4;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}

#titletext {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -65px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span id="frontcolor"></span>
<span id="titletext">Autorzy</span>
```

Comment: What does the `revBackDrop` animation look like?

Comment: `height: 100%;` doesn't mean anything unless an ancestor has a height

Comment: Hi there, @sitaragiema! Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question doesn't really have enough detail to be answered. We can't see the animation in question. The more detail you add, the easier it is to help.

Comment: I agree with @AndyMercer that your question lacks necessary details, however, I know that z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky).

Answer (score 0):

As @Mike indicated above, an element needs a `position` in order for `z-index` to be effective.

See the example below. `#frontcolor` is assigned `position: relative` so you can adjust its `z-index` now. Clicking the button will change its `z-index` to make it appear either in front of or behind `#titletext`.

Adding the `position` attribute should allow you to do what you need with the animation on your site.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('switchBtn');
var span1 = document.getElementById('frontcolor');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // on click, switch which span is in front
  if (span1.style.zIndex == 0) {
    span1.style.zIndex = 2;
  } else {
    span1.style.zIndex = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
#frontcolor {
  position: relative;  /* added to apply z-index */
  z-index: 0;
  animation: revBackDrop 1s linear 0s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eceff4;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}

#titletext {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;  /* added to apply z-index */
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -65px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<span id="frontcolor">frontcolor span</span>
<span id="titletext">titletext span</span>

<br /><br />
<button id="switchBtn">Switch</button>
```